# Changing parent class attribute only for a specific input textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The below JavaScript code works but it changes for entire page:

```
$('.myFormInputWrap').css('float','none');
```

Comment: show you html as well, and it's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: without more information it is really hard to help. make a small example to illustrate the issue

Comment: <div class="myFormInputWrap myFormSafari" style="width: 60px; float: none;">  
      <div class="myFormInputInner">  
         <div>  
            <input id="qty" type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" value="10" class="myFormdone myFormInput" style="width: 76px;">  
         </div>  
      </div>  
</div>

Comment: Add more specific selector like `$('#id .myFormInputWrap')` to specify just a element you want to change.

Comment: The code around the input stmt is generated at runtime based on the css defined elsewhere. My code is just <input id="qty" type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" value="10"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can find closest div with the specified class which is parent of your input element:

```
$("#qty").closest('div.myFormInputWrap').css('float','none');
```